# How to index Custom field from logstash in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

Below is my logstash config file.

```
input {
  stdin{}
}  

filter {
  mutate {
    if(message =~ "*FF"){
    add_field => { "vname" => "olive" }
    }
    else{
    add_field => { "vname" => "popeye" }
    }
  }
}


output {
   stdout { codec => rubydebug }
   elasticsearch { 
            hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
            index => "servererrors"
        }
}
```

Below image shows my kibana output.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJANQ.png

The problem is i need to filter "olive" alone. As you can see a filter in and filter off for host field but it is not available for vname field.

[Filter Not available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wc8ql.png)

Below is my mapping file response for vname

```
"vname": {
            "type": "string",
            "store": true
          },
```

I am confused with templates and mappings. Please explain clearly.

Comment: What does "filter... alone" mean?

Comment: Sorry, i dont understand the question.@Alain Colins

Comment: You said, "The problem is i need to filter "olive" alone.", which is unclear to me.  Could you restate the problem in more detail?

Comment: I have edited my filter block. Hope now you can understand clearly.

Comment: please provide more info or nobody is able to help you, maybe read through http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have edited my question. Please Go through.

Answer (score 0):

Add "if" statement and grok plugin. You need parse this events separately. 
If you show your events i can help you with filter.

Comment: You mean with each tags for seperate events?

Comment: Each event is single document in the elasticsearch index. If your "olive" and  "popeve" fields from different events you need add 

if [message] =~ /olive/ {
 grok { etc. etc. ....

but if "olive" and "popeve" from single event i really dont understand your question

Comment: i have custom field called "vname" generated inside filter{}. the value to vname can be "olive" or "popeye" or any other value(based on my grok match criteria it may change). The problem is filtering field "olive" seperately in kibana. It shows "This field is not indexed thus unavailable for visulation and search" @akhambir

Answer (score 0):

Based on your recent edit, it looks like you're just a little backwards on the syntax:

```
filter {
    if [myField] == "myValue" {
        mutate {
            add_field => { ... }
        }
    }
    else {
        mutate {
            add_field => { ... }
        }
    }
}
```